# Is there a difference between "outdoor" and "open" spaces?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, differences

I am trying to describe public and private spaces in a city that encompass spaces such as balconies, courtyards, streets, and parks. Meaning, they are outside buildings' shells. Does "open" or "outdoor" fit better into this specific context? thanks!

Comment: This article https://mgerwingarch.com/m-gerwing/2011/07/28/architects-glossary-patio-terrace-veranda-deck-balcony is using "outdoor space" to describe areas within a property, like balconies or patios. For places like public parks, "green space" seems to be the preferred term, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_green_space, along with open-space/ open space preserve. Are you looking for a term that encompasses both concepts?

Comment: Hi @GrandTorini, yes I am looking for a term that encompasses both of those concepts!

Comment: I'm not aware of any that is in common use ... I would probably use something along the lines of "any outdoor or open space". If you can provide a sentence with a blank to fill it'd probably help other contributors in proposing additional options.

Comment: These and other terms are synonyms, with complex regions of overlap. I'd say '[in the] open' is among the least commonly used for balconies, bringing to mind the wide open spaces (to be found in some parts of the world) or revelations of secrets, but that 'outdoor' is not really the best choice for balconies either. An outdoor meeting: in the park, not in a building, say. // 'Outside' itself would usually be used for locations _just_ ouside (!) a building: an outside toilet; "I'll be outside on the balcony".  But 'outside' is very weak as a standalone title.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with Oxford Online Dictionary on this one.
"Outdoor" is defined as "used, happening or located outside rather than in a building", however, "open" in the sense you intend, is defined as "not surrounded by anything; not closed in".

In other words, "outdoor" refers to anything which is not inside a building, but it can still be in a constrained area. It might be a small balcony you're talking about; it's outdoor, but it definitely is not an open area.

"Open", on the other hand, is used when the area is not closed in or surrounded by things.

A good example might put things in perspective here:
After an earthquake it's recommended that we go to an "open" area, away from buildings in order to avoid falling objects.
However, not any "outdoor" area is a safe place after an earthquake, because you might still be surrounded by many falling objects.